# How to schedule mails in Mandrill with django djrill?

Tags: django, scheduling, mandrill

I try to send scheduled mails in django via djrill like that:

```
msg = EmailMessage(...)
msg.send_at = "2015-07-10 10:00:00"
msg.send()
```

The mail backend is djrill and the mails are all successfully send via mandrill just instant instead of the time I want.

Is there a way of debugging on mandrill (besides outbound activity in test mode)?

regards Johannes

Comment: Setting `send_at` like that looks ok. Have you checked the API logs, as suggested in the [troubleshooting guide](https://djrill.readthedocs.org/en/v1.4/troubleshooting/)? Remember that the datetime is assumed to be UTC if not specified - make sure you aren't getting timezones confused, and setting a time in the past.

Comment: Also, Mandrill charges a [fee for scheduled email](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582667-Can-I-schedule-a-message-to-send-at-a-specific-time-) (even in an otherwise-free account), so make sure you've set up funding for your Mandrill account.

Comment: Thank for your replies. I could find the error through a hint in the troubleshooting guide. I found the Mandrill API-Log which helped me to find my bug. thx for your help